# How to install web_entreprise addon on Docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, odoo

I've deployed odoo 14 on kubernetes and want to migrate from community to entreprise edition , how to install web_entreprise addon on docker image ?

Answer (score 0):

By default the docker image of Odoo (https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo) is a community version.

If you have bought an entreprise version you must be have access to a private Github repository.

Now solution can be :

- Odoo have a specific entreprise version docker image (I dont work with enterprise version from long time, I don't know if Odoo have a enterprise docker image)
- You could create your own Dockerfile based on Odoo image and add Odoo enterprise code in /mnt/extra-addons and after create your own image version.
- You can used docker-compose to mount your Odoo enterprise code in /mnt/extra-addons (docker-compose isn't a best practice on production)

Dockerfile example

```
from odoo:14

COPY ./enterprise/addons /mnt/extra-addons/
```

And after you can build your own image and use it.

Comment: Thnaks for the update, in fact we have bought an entreprise edition version but odoo does not have an Entreprise Docker image .  How can i get odoo entreprise code in order to add it to the custom docker image .

Comment: It's explain in my preview message. You need create a Dockerfile and past my Dockerfile example. `COPY ./enterprise/addons /mnt/extra-addons/` will add the odoo enterprise code in the docker image. PS the entreprise code is on github of Odoo.

Comment: Thanks for the update, i do it with another method i've downloaded the Entreprise package and added it to the Dockerfile and build my image .  It works fine and all my data have been migrated but when i restart wy pod and  try to log in i got a blanck page . By checking the web consol i see : web.assets.common.css NOT FOUND , web.assests.frontend.css NOT FOUND . Any idea ?

Comment: Probably your ir.attachment is broken. Could you juste start your page in debug mode ? (?debug=assets#). Because by default Odoo merge all css and jss in one file to optimize the loading time.

Comment: Have you contacted Odoo to ask if there is a script to migrate from community to enterprise for the DB ?

Comment: Yes , with debug mode woks fine , should i use the debug mode always ?

Comment: No no, it's not the solution. I think it's just your cache. Try open your Odoo in an other browser or full clear your browser cache.

Comment: i've contacted the support n times , there is no document for k8s deployment . For the DB i did the migration form saas to on-prem